# How to create a square button that adjusts to list item height?

Tags: android, android-button

In a Listview I want create a square button that is as wide as the list item is high. I don't want to set fixed width and height as it should work for different resolutions.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your [layout xml file tell it to fill it's parent](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params):

```
<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" .... ></Button>
```

Or if you are using the API I think you should be able to use [setLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)):

```
myButton.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: the row consists of a TextView and a Button, the button should be has wide as the row is high. If a smaller font is used the button should adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Use **density independent pixel** (dip) which is a virtual pixel unit to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.